# How do I render form ChoiceField images next to choices without breaking the form?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I am trying to render the images of the choices next to their respective choice. Attempting to do so will not save the form as valid so I have become lost at what to do. I've tried both methods below and I have no idea why one works and the other doesn't, could I get some tips?

```
#Form:

    class ServerGroupForm(forms.Form):
        OPTIONS = (
            ("pic1", "https://i.imgur.com/tMahp6U.png"),
            ("pic2", "https://i.imgur.com/b76nwsj.gif"),
            ("pic3", "https://i.imgur.com/qzEcfyX.png Lover"),
            ("pic4", "https://i.imgur.com/kdc7UF7.png"),
            ("pic5", "https://i.imgur.com/ynWJ13W.gif"),
            ("pic6!", "https://i.imgur.com/goHFWsp.png"),
            ("pic7", "https://i.imgur.com/b76nwsj.gif"),
            ("pic8", "https://i.imgur.com/KPgKm79.png"),
            ("pic9", "https://i.imgur.com/7KtEV1i.png"),
            ("pic10", "https://i.imgur.com/7KtEV1i.png"),
            ("pic11", "https://i.imgur.com/FXfo773.png")
        )
        servergroups = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=OPTIONS)    
#View:
    def sendmessage(msg):
        #Other code sends msg to user, not includes so this isn't long
    def select_server_group(request):
        form = ServerGroupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            servergroups = form.cleaned_data['servergroups']
            sendmessage(msg=servergroups)
            return redirect('/')
        return render_to_response('webts3/selcectsgroup.html', {'form':form },
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))    

#HTML: Works but no icons
    <section class="login">
        <div class="titulo">Create a channel</div>
        <form method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
            <table border="0">
                {{ form.as_table }}
            </table>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger" value="Submit" style="margin-top: 10px;">
         </form>
    </section>    
#HTML: Icons but not working
    <form method='post' action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}>
        <table>
            {% for x,y in form.fields.servergroups.choices %}
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{ x }}" value="{{ x }}"><img src={{ y }}</img></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: I observe that in the "Works but no icons" snippet, you have included the `csrf_token` but in the "not working" section, it is missing. Is that a copy-paste error for posting this question, or is it missing from your actual HTML in the problematic situation?

Also helpful would be what the "not working" error message is

Comment: Copy and paste error, I edited it when I noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` attribute of the field should not be `{{ x }}`. It should be `"servergroups"`.

Note you'd also need to have some logic that determines if the field is already selected, for when for example the form is being redisplayed after validation errors.

Comment: I think I didn't properly ask my question. I've done what you said in my own code but I'm still having the issue with the image displaying html not working.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You said that your second version shows the icons but does not submit the data. So, change the `name` attribute of the HTML field to "servergroups", as I said.

Comment: I mean't I tried your method and still no luck, I set name="{{ servergroups }}" and tried name="{{ form.fields.servergroups }}".

Comment: I didn't say either of those. It's not a variable. `name="servergroups"`. (Edited to clarify.)

Comment: Ah, I see, I was just in that mindset, Thank You very much. It's 5AM and I can finally sleep.